# Is there a proper procedure to include $PREFIX (and other variables) in debian/package.install?

Tags: dpkg, deb

I'm trying to convert an existing debian/rules file of a package to use `debhelper`.  The current rules file employs rules which specify an installation prefix (via a variable).

Is there a way for me to include/specify the prefix (and possibly other variables, like ones denoting the architecture) in the `.install` file?

As an example, if built on a 64-bit machine with the prefix set to `/opt`, I'd like to be able to install the package files to `${PREFIX}/package/${ARCH}`.

Comment: I would still like this to be answered, consider my similar use case:
I have a makefile generating a custom kernel module. My install file looks like `*.ko /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/misc/`, it would be nice for that kernel version to not be hard coded, but instead supplied via makefile variable.

Comment: What I ended up doing was creating `package.install.in` files with `@PREFIX@` and `@ARCH@` in appropriate places.  Inside the debian/rules file I have an `edit` rule where I do a global `sed` on all target `.in` files putting the output in `package.install`.  It's not 'standard' but I don't consider it to be a kludgy workaround.  Correspondingly, the `clean` rule includes the `package.install` files so that they're removed.

Comment: thanks! that would work, an override_dh_install: + some magic to grab the variable from makefile.

Comment: @Piotrek You should put an example of your `.in` trick in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like the files in debian/ should be as architecture agnostic and standard as possible.  This means taking care of architecture-specific steps at build time and making 'standard' files (binaries, libraries) available for the *extra* files in /debian.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Kevin, I decided to use a `dh_override_install` rule:

```
dh_override_install:
    ARCH=`uname -p`; \
    if test "$${ARCH}" != "x86_64"; then \
        sed -i -e "s/x86_64/$${ARCH}/g" debian/*.install; \
    fi
    dh_install
```

Don't forget that the `debian/rules` file is a `makefile`, which means you are expected to have tabs for indentation.

The `$$` is to escape the `$` so as to reference the variable I define in the shell, not a `make` variable.

Since my files are for `x86_64` by default, I skip on the `sed` in that case. Here is an example of my `.install` files:

```
usr/include/uv.h                              usr/include/
usr/include/uv/*                              usr/include/uv/
usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.a              usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libuv.pc   usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/
```

And the reason I need to include the architecture to pick just some files is because I have a developer version (`libuv.a`) and a runtime version (`libuv.so`). I have another package where I can do without such because I can just copy the whole `usr/lib` folder at once. Here, I had to have support for the architecture. Unfortunate that the Debian packager doesn't yet know about such. It would be really useful in this situation and I would imagine that it happens all the time...

Source: [libuv1/debian/rules](https://github.com/m2osw/libuv1-snap/blob/master/debian/rules)